# What are the supported browsers and devices for Google's Closure Javascript library?

Tags: google-closure-library

Where do you find out if Android, Safari (iOs) etc are supported by the Google Closure libraries?

Comment: Sub-question: do you already know of a list of the desktop browsers that are officially supported by the GCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCL supports all of them. That is the nice thing about GCL, a platform independent Library, that abstracts nasty platform/browser specific bugs.

Comment: Accepting answer, it would just be nice to know where their unit tests or similar information is to cater for the different devices.

Comment: given that Google uses closure library extensively, I would assume so

Answer (score 0):

I found the following way to search the source code, where you can look for words like iPhone etc to see what specific handling they have for specific devices.

Code search for *iphone*: http://www.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=iphone%20package:http://closure-library%5C.googlecode%5C.com

Although [searching for *blackberry* doesn't return anything](http://www.google.com/codesearch#epIciakqvFc/&q=package%3ahttp://closure-library%5C.googlecode%5C.com%20blackberry), which means that it doesn't cater for Blackberry's Javascript?